# SQL - Conditional Window with multiple dates

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql, window, conditional-statements

```
Table A

| Customer | Transaction_Date | Complaint_Date |
|----------|------------------|----------------|
| A        | 1                | 2              |
| A        | 1                | 3              |
| A        | 2                | 3              |
| B        | 1                | 2              |
| B        | 1                | 2              |
| B        | 2                | 3              |
| C        | 2                | 3              |
```

For the table above, I would like to calculate the number of complaints per customer in the last x days, taking into account when the complaint occurred.
i.e. the complaint should only be counted if it occurred before the transaction date

i.e

```
| Customer | Transaction_Date | Complaint_Date | Count |
|----------|------------------|----------------|-------|
| A        | 1                | 2              | 0     |
| A        | 1                | 3              | 0     |
| A        | 2                | 3              | 1     |
| B        | 1                | 2              | 0     |
| B        | 1                | 2              | 0     |
| B        | 2                | 3              | 2     |
| C        | 2                | 3              | 0     |
```

Currently, I am counting the number of transactions (records), with a partition of customer, transaction date and complaint date and then joining back to customer and transaction date, if the complaint date is less than the transaction date and transaction date is within the range of x days.
I then calculate a final sum over a window of x days, partition by customer, as the above results in a count for each transaction date and customer

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Are the dates really numbers?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this by using a simple where condition. Assuming the date fields are stored in the date format, calculating for the last 10 days (This is in SQL server):

```
select Customer,count(*)
from table 
where Complaint_date<transaction_date
      and Complaint_date between GETDATE()-10 and GETDATE()
Group by Customer
```

Hope this helps.

Edit: You can try doing a self join here:

```
;with tableA as
(select 'A' as customer,1 as Transaction_date,2 as Complaint_date union all
select 'A',1,3 union all
select 'A',2,3 union all
select 'B',1,2 union all
select 'B',1,2 union all
select 'B',2,3 union all
select 'C',2,3)

select a.Customer,a.transaction_date,count(b.Complaint_date) as cnt
from tableA a
left join tableA b on a.customer=b.customer
      and a.transaction_date>=b.Complaint_date
Group by a.Customer,a.transaction_date
```

This produces the following output:

```
Customer Transaction_Date Cnt
A        1                0
A        2                1
B        1                0
B        2                2
C        2                0
```

If you want the same output as mentioned in your answer, you can join this output back to the original table:

```
;with tableA as
(select 'A' as customer,1 as Transaction_date,2 as Complaint_date union all
select 'A',1,3 union all
select 'A',2,3 union all
select 'B',1,2 union all
select 'B',1,2 union all
select 'B',2,3 union all
select 'C',2,3)

select x.*,y.cnt
from tableA x
inner join
(select a.Customer,a.transaction_date,count(b.Complaint_date) as cnt
from tableA a
left join tableA b on a.customer=b.customer
      and a.transaction_date>=b.Complaint_date
Group by a.Customer,a.transaction_date) y
ON x.customer=y.customer and x.transaction_date=y.Transaction_date
```

Comment: Not quite, this would give a count of 0 as complaint date is never less than transaction date

Comment: i.e. the complaint should only be counted if it occurred before the transaction date, what did you mean by this? Are you looking to cross reference all records?

Comment: Exactly, I need the count per customer and day with a window function

Comment: I have added an edit for your requirement...Does this give what you are looking for?

Comment: I need the count per customer and transaction date, I don't think this can be done without a window function

Comment: I don't know why you think a window function is necessary...I have added an edit to include the transaction_date in the output

Comment: This does not include the result for every day, where the count would be 0

Comment: I have added another edit, to get the same result as mentioned in the question...let me know if this does the trick

Comment: I'm looking to do this without a self join as that is the solution I currently have. Also want to keep in mind this is a huge dataset and one may want to calculate the count per shop and day too, from the same initial dataset.